# Is there an easy way to configure an Ubuntu system to function as a proxy/file server from behind an NAT?

Tags: internet, remote

Sorry for the long question, but the situation/desire is quite complex. Here is my setup: I have a laptop which I carry around everywhere and I have a desktop sitting at home, connected to the internet through a router using NAT.

My objective is to create a connection from my laptop to my desktop that can allow me to (in order of priority):

1. Use the desktop as a proxy server
2. Access files on the desktop remotely
3. Control said desktop from the laptop using VNC or similar.

Now here is the scene. I have already looked up and tried several ways to achieve the above goals.

1. Teamviewer - I used it and didn't like it. This is not an option.
2. SSH - This seems ideal, I have figured a way to use this for both proxy and file sharing. However, I am currently unable to connect it due to the NAT. I have a separate thread trying to get that to work [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198608/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-desktop-behind-a-router).
3. VPN - I've figured out how to use this method for proxy, but not file sharing. However this faces the same problem as the above: I can't get it to connect through the NAT.

Does anyone have any other solutions for what I want? Otherwise, if there are solutions to connecting through the NAT, please tell me (in the other thread).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure using Squid proxy server and Dansguardian content filtering combination The following is the link and the steps

http://kamleshgosavi.blogspot.in/2011/01/dansguardian-content-filtering-with.html

Dansguardian Content Filtering With Squid Transparent Proxy On Ubuntu Dansguardian Content Filtering With Squid Transparent Proxy On Ubuntu

sudo apt-get install squid3 sudo nano /etc/squid3/squid.conf

(Search for http_port 3128 and add following ) http_port 3128 transparent

(Search for INSERT and add following )

acl localnet src 192.168.2.0/24

http_access allow localnet http_access allow localhost

sudo /etc/init.d/squid3 restart For squid in detail follow the below link dont follow the IPtable part from this link

Comment: I tried this. I couldn't manage to configure the squid server.

Comment: try this link you can skip step 3 and step 4  from the link 1) http://kamleshgosavi.blogspot.in/2011/01/squid3-transparent-proxy-setup.html    let me know where u get stuck

Comment: Also this one haven't tried this but http://codeghar.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/ubuntu-12-04-ipv4-nat-gateway-and-dhcp-server/